# jQuery selector combination to get to my element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Okay so looking at the image, the highlighted section is the element i need to get too. I need to store the data-id value which is 2391 in the example above.

So starting from the anchor tag with the data-id value of "2392", how do i achieve this.

This is what i have done with no joy.

```
// This is finding the element, currentID is 2392. 
var currentReview = $('.modelLink[data-id="'+ currentID +'"]');

var nextID = currentReview.closest('tr').next().children('td').next().next().next().children('.modalLink').data('id');
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do all the td got the same child? anchor with this class etc. Or is it always the last?

Comment: Cant you directly target the data-id ? If not you can probably use find()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var currentReview = $('.modelLink[data-id='+ currentID +']');

var nextID = currentReview.closest('tr').next().find('td a.modalLink').data('id');
```

Comment: console.log(nextID) prints 'undefined'

Comment: @MatthewSmart - It will definetly work I am sure if you given html is right

Comment: it worked when i did this: var nextID = currentReview.closest('tr').next().children('td:last').children('.modelLink').data('id');

Comment: @MatthewSmart - Thanks Glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to traverse from one deeply-nested anchor to another, just grab all of the IDs into an array and traverse the array--much easier!

```
// Put all anchor IDs into an array
var ids = [];
$.each("a.modelLink", function( index, value ) {
  ids.push(value.attr("data-id"));
});

// Creates: ids[0] = 2391, ids[1] = 2392, etc.
```

After that, you'll be able to traverse the anchors without worrying about DOM traversal.

```
// This is finding the element, currentID is 2392.
var currentID = 2392;
var currentReview = $('.modelLink[data-id="'+ currentID +'"]');

// Ensure we do not go out of bounds
current_index = ids.indexOf(currentID);
if(current_index >= 0 && current_index < ids.length - 1) {
  nextID = ids[current_index + 1];
}
else {
  // Start over from the beginning
  nextID = ids[0];
}

// Easily assign the nextReview
nextReview = $('.modelLink[data-id="'+ nextID +'"]');
```

Comment: How does that help him solve the problem of getting from one specific link to the next matching link in the next row? (presumably from the one "clicked" - as it is an achor)

Comment: Im typing this on my mobile, so bear with me. I'll edit :)

Comment: problem is the next target can have a random id, so it could be 15 for example then the next one could be 4876

Comment: @MatthewSmart it would still index them in order in the array. `ids[0] = 123, ids[1] = 2391, ids[2] = 4556, etc.`

Comment: That is a lot of code, just to find the next matching anchor after the one clicked. Better off using jQuery DOM traversal and avoid the overheads (code + memory).

Comment: JS doesn't provide a handy `next` or `prev` for arrays, otherwise the code would be very small. It depends on what all you try to do with the anchors, but this would be the most flexible way to do it.